# Include a framework inside an NSBundle that is loaded at runtime

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbundle, dynamic-loading

In a macOS app I am loading bundles at runtime as "Plugins".

If one of those plugins requires a framework (lets go with a CSV importer for example that requires some CSV parsing framework) how can I set this up?

Obviously I do not want to link against the CSV parsing framework in my main app but the main app will be the one that needs to resolve the symbols of that framework (loading the plugin/bundle means that for all intents and purposes the code of the plugin is part of the main app).

I do store the URL for each plugin I load, so there's possibly a way of telling the main application to look for any embedded frameworks inside the bundle?

How would I actually go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you link the frameworks for the plug-in, they additional frameworks will be loaded when the plug-in is loaded.

So all you need to do is:

```
[[[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:@"..."] load]
```

Comment: Sry for answering so late. Well I don't want to link the app to the framework that is used by the plugin. But it did work when I just included the framework inside the plugin's Frameworks directory. I guess that's what you meant? So I'll mark this as the correct answer.